# Install Pyqt to alternative Python Version on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt, installation

I am using IPython Notebook and want to ramp things up and get the qt console going as well.. But I use Python 2.7 (not the default install) on Ubuntu 10.10 I don't quite get how to install Pyqt to this alternative Python,, I have it installed to the default Python 2.6, but how can I get it installed to Python2.7? Other packages install with easy_install2.7 but this does not work. All the guides I see (including here on SO) do not address the install to a non-default Python version?

I got SIP installed using configure.py and make and make install but My Configure.py is failing for pyqt saying:

```
tom@tom-Satellite-A105:~/Downloads/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.1$ sudo python2.7 configure.py
Error: Make sure you have a working Qt v4 qmake on your PATH or use the -q
argument to explicitly specify a working Qt v4 qmake.
```

Given that Configure.py should create the make file I'm lost..

Comment: What about: download sources, `tar -zxf...`, `cd PyQt...`,  `python2.7 configure.py`?

Comment: I assume I have to install SIP 1st? Same way?

Comment: Do you have Qt installed ? If yes wouldn't updating the PATH variable
so that 'qmake' is in the path (as hinted in the error message) help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the development packages of Qt4.  I don't know the package name on Ubuntu, look for "qt-devel" or something similar.

Comment: Just figured it out! Thanks, wished that the pyqt package called that out as a dependency/prereq..

Comment: @dartdog: Mmmh, isn't it common knowledge that you need the devel package of a library if your compiling against it?

Comment: The implication on the pyqt site seems to be that it has all that is needed in its package...